# Erro conection JDBC of App JSP in Openshift

Tags: openshift

I'm three days trying a solution for jdbc mysql connection from my app on OpenShift. 
It's a simple app, JSP. Not JSF and not Hibernate.

The error that shows me is:

---

java.lang.NullPointerException

com.brazil.jdbc.UsuarioDAO.autenticar (UsuarioDAO.java: 186)

---

This line of code is what I use to create the connection object.

I've used the "port-forward rhc -a teste5" command 
And tb the "export" within the rhc, to obtain the variables.

I've tried to modify the following ways below, but all without success:

---

```
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.7.202.2:3306/teste5", "adminXnZRJkD", "******");

con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}");

con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://adminXnZRJkD:******@127.7.202.2:3306");

con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL}");

con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL}");
```

---

My app was created as jbossews-2.0 with phpmyadmin and mysql-5.5-4. I do not know whether to configure an external file.

Please someone see a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking out this KB article about how to use the pre configured mysql & postgresql connections in the java cartridges and see if it helps: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399720

Comment: Thank you brother! 
The article was very relevant, and allowed me to identify that the problem was not the connection but the jdbc drive.